# Apache2 password protected Vhost configuration

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

I have a problem with a password protected vhost on apache2 and debian (7).

It's a server which hosts several vhost. They are all online for now. I need to restrict access only for one of them. (www.acticia.net)

I do not want to use .htaccess while it is not the correct way for apache.

Here is my vhost conf in site-available :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@acticia.net
ServerName  acticia.net
ServerAlias www.acticia.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/acticia.net/
<Directory /var/www/acticia.net/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentication required"
    AuthUserfile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
    Require valide-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/acticia.net-error_log
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/acticia.net-access_log
```

/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd has been generated by htpasswd (from apache2)
The site claims that "Authentication required", ask for a login and a password then, ask it again, and again and again ...

Tested under chorimum and iceweasel (up to date for a deb7).

I read apache2 wiki, apache2 docs and a certain part of the www for this subject, didn't understood my mistake !

Thanks for the helps guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require valide-user should be  Require valid-user

Comment: GREAT ! I re-read my code for a while and didn't see that ! It is working now ... You saved one more day of my life Özgür ! THX !!